# C++ Stack Trace Debugging in Powershell

Tags: c++, windows, powershell

## Problem

I am writing a program in C++ using the MinGW-w64 GCC compiler, in Windows 11 through PowerShell, to compile the program. The program compiles and runs perfectly, but I am having an issue with the stack trace for exceptions.

A simple example of the program is:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    if(a > 1) throw "This is an exception!";
    std::cout << "Program runs!" << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run the program:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -o main.exe main.cpp
./main.exe
```

I would expect something like:

```
Folder> g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -o main.exe main.cpp
Folder> ./main.exe
An exception has occurred in main.cpp line whatever ... bla bla bla
Folder>
```

Instead, I am getting:

```
Folder> g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -o main.exe main.cpp
Folder> ./main.exe
Folder>
```

that is, no stack trace whatsoever.

## Test

On the other hand, if I run the program:

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    if(a > 1) throw "This is an exception!";
    std::cout << "Program runs!" << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

The output printed is:

```
Folder> g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -o main.exe main.cpp
Folder> ./main.exe
Program runs!
Folder>
```

that is, the correct output is generated.

## Question

How do I get the stack trace from the exception? Of course, the program that I am compiling is far more complicated and has many classes, inheritance, etc.; so a stack trace for any exceptions is desired.

## Other information/assertions

- No, I don't want to use any IDE; currently using VS Code and it is what I want.
- No, I don't want to use CMake or Make; too convoluted and an overkill for what I have and need.
- No, I don't want to change to Linux; as much as I like Linux, this must be done in Windows.
- No, I don't want to change compiler; it is what it is and I am sure that this is more a Windows thing, because the stack trace works perfectly fine on Mac OSX and Linux with the same compiler.

Comment: To see a stack trace you should use your debugger, gdb in your case. You should also compile with the `-g` switch and without the `-O3` switch.

Comment: So, there really is no way of showing the stack trace in the PowerShell/command line window? I don't need anything as sophisticated as "gdb" or anything of the sort. A simple stack trace displaying below the program will do.

Comment: @john that's not true. Exceptions can be thrown normally in Windows. The debug switch is just to prevent some optimizations that interfere with debugging, and to leave debug symbols there

Comment: @Andrumen1 check the compiler output to see why the exception message isn't printed out

Comment: For comparison, what output do you get if you run the “throwing” version of main.exe in a regular command prompt on Windows?

Comment: None, I also tried it and I get exactly the same result as in PowerShell.